# Is it appropriate for a site admin to curtail requested information from a user?

Tags: discussion

**Update**: I realized that this post attracted a lot of downvotes maybe because it's lacking context.

A question got posted on The Workplace SE. I wrote an answer to it. I realized I can slightly edit the answer. While I was midway editing the answer, the post was deleted by a site moderator.

The linked question below is me seeking the reasoning from the moderator (on The Workplace Meta) behind deleting the question as I couldn't see a reason for deletion.

---

I recently posted this on The Workplace Meta:

- [Reasoning behind deleting a question?](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6218/reasoning-behind-deleting-a-question)

It was duly answered by a site moderator to whom it was addressed. (**Clarification**: *The moderator was addressed by pinging them in a comment, as it is about an action performed by them. I am only interested in a reasonable explanation, irrespective of the person it comes from.*).

However, I don't feel satisfied with the answer.

Now I am curious to know, if as per SE sites policy, is it appropriate/allowed for a site moderator to curtail information from a user?

I want to note there's nothing against any individual person here. I am generically curious if as per site governance rules, can a moderator (with access to certain special privileges) deny giving a reason for a question by a regular user of the site? And if yes, is it documented anywhere?

I understand there may be generic cases where withholding such information may be necessary. I am curious to learn about such condition(s).

Comment: Moderators are bound by the privacy policy, and aren't going to be giving out personal information.  I don't see anything wrong with *asking*, but the only one who can give you insight into it is likely going to be the asker themselves.

Comment: In general, mods are not required to, nor should they, reveal private information about other users.  Sometimes we just need to acknowledge and accept that a mod is abiding by privacy guidelines when we are told by a mod that "No, it is not possible, but it was for good reason. That is all I feel is appropriate to say at the moment."  You are not entitled to know information that entails actions by mods with respect to other users.  Think about an asker asking on a meta.site.se about you and actions on posts by you.  I'm suggesting that sometimes, it is none of our business.

Comment: As I said, I am just curious to know if any such act is as per site governance and policies. I'd be perfectly okay to accept it.

Comment: Just a bit of a semantic nitpicking: that's a site moderator (a user elected by other users of that community). SE sites don't have admins, but a better analogy for an admin would probably be community managers, which are SE employees.

Comment: Yep - we typically don't have to provide that information or are not allowed too as pointed out (privacy).  There are other reasons as well.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only real reason a moderator has for deleting something is "leaving it there would be against site policy as I interpret it." They may say a longer or shorter sentence, but that's the reason. They are tasked with understanding site policy, recognizing whether a question, answer, or comment is not aligned with site policy, and then deciding whether to edit it, delete it, leave a comment, or send a private message to the author.

You don't say why you were unsatisfied with the answer, but my guess is that "the question didn't meet site policy and couldn't be edited to do so" was too vague for you. Sometimes, mods or other users explain, but it's important to know that explaining decisions isn't part of a mod's duties, and so refraining from such explanations isn't "curtailing" or "with-holding" at all. The more specific a question you ask, the more specific answers you will usually get.

Comment: There is also zero obligation for an explanation to be given, if giving an explanation would violate privacy issues. In fact, if that were the case, then it would be *expected* that no explanation be given. In the event of confidentiality, giving such an explanation would be *shirking* moderator obligations.